# Exiting Pygame by pressing Space

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a situation. Me and my acquaintance nearly finished a project where a loading bar loads very slowly. However, we get to the the final part, and the space key assign won't exit the game. Here is the code:

```
while progress/2 >= 100:
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(exitPic, (75, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in a loop:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    pygame.quit()
```

This tests if the key Space is pressed, this will quit Pygame.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
def test():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and progress > 99:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE
                    break
```

its checking for a key down and if the progress is 100% and if the that is true it checks what key is down and if it is space it ends the program

Comment: The change in the code didn't really change anything. We still can't leave the game.